# Can't deploy Lambda Function in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to execute **serverless deploy** command to deploy my lambda function.But it is showing

> user is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:UpdateStack on
>   resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-south-1

What policy should be attached to deploy lambda function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS user you are using for deploying serverless template should have updateStack permission for cloudformation.

> {
>       "Effect":"Allow",
>       "Action": "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
>       "Resource":"*" 
>   }

Use [policy simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp?#) to check if user has required permissions.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to set permission in details

Comment: @Dnyanesh Create a new policy in IAM with {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cloudformation:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}. This provides full permission to cloudformation. Add this policy to the user you are using to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I simply created a user called "serverless-admin" with only "Programmatic Access" and attached the policy "AdministratorAccess". I DIDNT check the "AWS Management Console Access" feature. Then simply write down the "Key" and the "secret" and use that for configuring serverless aka aws client.

This way you can be sure that everything serverless does when it comes to deploying your stack is allowed. Perhaps you can do it more strict but this way you dont run into any issues.

Comment: I would recommend against creating a deploy user with full admin privileges, especially if you're going to store the key and secret somewhere. Either deploy as you using your current profile or create a deploy user with only the access it requires.